# How can I get a list of all languages translation that a node has?

Tags: i18n-l10n, 9

I'm trying to get a list of language translations that a node has in `theme_preprocess_node()`. I have the node object and can check for a translation on a one-by-one basis, if I have the list of languages. What I need is a list of all the translations for the node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [getTranslationLanguages()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21TranslatableInterface.php/function/TranslatableInterface%3A%3AgetTranslationLanguages/):

```
$languages = $node->getTranslationLanguages();

foreach ($languages as $id => $language) {
  print $node->getTranslation($id)->label();
}
```